# Evaluate $\int _0^4 \sqrt{t} \cdot e^{-st} dt$ and $2\int _4^\infty \cos(t-4) \cdot e^{-st} dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate $\int _0^4 \sqrt{t} \cdot e^{-st} dt$ and $2\int _4^\infty \cos(t-4) \cdot e^{-st} dt$

I tried doing the first integral by parts but kept running into a loop and wasn't sure how to solve it.

How do you also solve the second integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we integrate by parts once, we get

$$\begin{align}\int_0^4\sqrt te^{-st}\ dt&=\frac1s\left(-\sqrt te^{-st}\bigg|_0^4+\frac12\int_0^4\frac{e^{-st}}{\sqrt t}\ dt\right)\\&=\frac1s\left(-2e^{-4s}+\frac12\int_0^4\frac{e^{-st}}{\sqrt t}\ dt\right)\end{align}$$

And by letting $st=u^2$, we get an [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function):

$$\begin{align}&=\frac1s\left(-2e^{-4s}+\int_0^{2\sqrt{s}}e^{-u^2}\ du\right)\\&=\frac1s\left(-2e^{-4s}+\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\operatorname{erf}(2\sqrt s)\right)\end{align}$$

[The second integral is doable in two integration by parts, as shown in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-U3-et-dEjQ).

Comment: Ewewew. Again, DUIS beats IBP here in my book :) Good answer nevertheless!

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Well of course.  Anyways, haven't seen you in a while, how have you been?

Comment: Eh, working on a lot of college atm. Taking 30 credits on top of high school classes. And studying complex analysis in depth. And programming a server in PHP without any prior knowledge of PHP or how servers work. So you know, keeping busy. I still browse the site daily, but I haven't posted much recently, you are correct

Comment: Haha, okay then.  Good luck with your studies!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint For First Integral:**
$$\int _0^4 \sqrt{t} \cdot e^{-st} \mathrm{d}t$$
$u = \sqrt{t} $
$$= 2\int_0^2 u^2e^{-su^2} \mathrm{d} u = -2\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\int_0^2 e^{-su^2}\mathrm{d}u$$
We now have to bring the Error Function into play

---

**Hints for Second Integral:**

1. Rewrite Integral

$$\int _4^\infty \cos(t-4) e^{-st} \mathrm{d} t \stackrel{t-4 \to t}{=} e^{-4s}\int _0^\infty \cos(t) e^{-st} \mathrm{d}t = e^{-4s}\Re\left(\int _0^\infty e^{ti-ts} \mathrm{d} t \right)$$

2. Note that
   $$\int e^{tn} \mathrm{d}t = \frac{e^{tn}}{n}$$